# How can I create a video DVD with multiple titles from a single-titled DVD?

Tags: linux, dvd, authoring

I have an unencrypted DVD that is one big title, ie you cannot skip next / prev. What I want to do is reauthor the DVD with title at certain points, so that I can skip next / prev when watching it.

I'm using Ubuntu 8.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use

> [DVDStyler](http://www.dvdstyler.de/) is a cross-platform free DVD authoring application for the creation of professional-looking DVDs. It allows not only burning of video files on DVD that can be played practically on any standalone DVD player, but also creation of individually designed DVD menus. It is Open Source Software and is completely free.

or perhaps

> ['Q' DVD](http://qdvdauthor.sourceforge.net/) The goal of 'Q' DVD-Author is to provide a complete DVDAuthoring solution for Linux with the emphasis of ease of use and a complete set of functionality.